# In jsp directive

Tags: java, jsp

I need to include the following tag to my entire application `JSP` pages but is there any way we can include that in only one location and used in entire project.

Here is the tag;-

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
```

Comment: No, it is a directive.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

A solution is using tiles, so you can create structure:

https://tiles.apache.org/framework/tutorial/basic/pages.html

You can build a web page layout and put all your configuration like:

- content type
- link
- link js

in one place, preferably into header section and display everytime a different body (another jsp).